# Using move semantics for a cast operator

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two classes `foo`, and `bar` that are fairly well-related, by which I mean that they contain common data members.

I have a cast operator `operator bar() const;` in the `foo` class.

I also have a function `func` that takes a `bar`.

If I call `func` with an anonymous temporary `foo` then the cast operator will be called. But as I don't need the `foo`, can I declare some sort of *move cast* so explicitly optimising out any unnecessary copies?

Comment: Could you please post your example in actual code?

Comment: This is a **conversion** operator. There is no such thing as a cast operator. A cast is something you write in your code to request a conversion, but it is not the only way to get a conversion.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this because "why isn't this code working" questions need an MCVE - this is *not* a "why isn't this code working" question. While a code example certainly wouldn't hurt this question, it is quite understandable without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your compiler supports ref-qualifiers on member functions (a C++11 feature), you can:

```
operator bar() const &
{
  return bar(the_common_data);
}

operator bar() &&
{
  return bar(std::move(the_common_data));
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afd2c2ea2ebe29bc)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can using `r-value this` syntax:

```
operator bar() &&{ /* std::move(...); */ }
```